# How to add percentages in Legend for a cataegorical data column in Leaflet Visualization in R

Tags: r, r-leaflet

My dataset has below shown column.
col = (yes, no, no, yes, yes, no, no, no, yes)
I would like to show this in my legend along with the percentage of categorical values of reponses in Leaflet Visualization in R. Just like the below example.

[output I expect](https://www.ourdialects.uk/maps/meal/). If you observe the legend in this website I linked [here](https://www.ourdialects.uk/maps/meal/) , they have shown the percentage of categorical variable in their dataset into their legend along with the count N(total count). I expect the same output, Can someone help me with this ?